# I am trying to plot clusters with unique color but getting error

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am just trying to plot x, y and then color them with clusters. Each cluster should have unique color. But i am getting error. I tried without using numpy array but still getting error.

" c of shape (5113,) not acceptable as a color sequence for x with size 5113, y with size 5113""

```
x = np.array(df['ip_indexed'])
print(x.shape)
y = np.array(df['geohash_indexed'])
print(y.shape)
labels = np.array(df['clusters'])
print(labels.shape)

''' output. 
(5113,)
(5113,)
(5113,)
 '''

LABEL_COLOR_MAP = {9066 : 'r',
               9068: 'silver',
               17182 : 'k',
               17183: 'c',
               17184: 'indigo',
               17185:  'tan',
               17186: 'plum',
               17187: 'yello',
               17188:'olive',
               17189:'deeppink'
               }

label_color = np.array([LABEL_COLOR_MAP[l] for l in labels])
label_color.shape

plt.figure(figsize=(50, 10))
plt.xlabel("ip_address", fontsize= 20)
plt.ylabel("geohash", fontsize= 20)
plt.title("clusters", fontsize= 50)
colors = np.random.rand(5113)
plt.scatter(x, y , c = label_color)

ValueError: c of shape (5113,) not acceptable as a color sequence for x with size 5113, y with size 5113
```

Comment: Can you share an example with few data points, let's say `x` and `y` with size `3`?

Comment: `"yello"` is no valid color. Appart there is no reason this would fail. Can you provide a [mcve], i.e. a runnable code such that one may reproduce this?

Comment: x= [414 414 414 ... 420 421 422]
y=[  0   0   2 ... 210 211 212]

Comment: labels = [ 9066  9066  9068 ... 17187 17188 17189]

Comment: yello is not an issue. I corrected it and still same issue.

Comment: With `x= [414, 414, 414, 420, 421, 422];
y=[ 0, 0, 2, 210, 211, 212]` the code runs just fine for me. That's why I was asking for a [mcve] that actually reproduces the issue.

Comment: Getting the same error here...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue moments ago and stumbled across this post in searching for a solution. Things that I can definitively say:
In the line `plt.scatter(x, y , c = label_color)` the shape of `x`, `y`, and `c` needs to be the same and, I **believe**, all three are best if they are a pandas dataframe. The shape of all of my successful objects was `(5113, 1)` rather than your `(5113,)`. I recognize that you are testing the shape in your `print()` statements, but something seems amiss.

I am by no means a professional and I may be wrong in some of this, but this was how I came to my own solution. Hopefully it might nudge you and others in the right direction.