# ValueError: c of shape (7303,) not acceptable as a color sequence for x

Tags: python, arrays, axes

I am trying to visualize some data in Axes3D, but I'm getting an error that I don't know how to solve.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances_argmin_min

%matplotlib inline
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16, 9)
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

These are the axes for my 3D figure:

```
X = np.array(piv_tb[['00:00', '01:00', '02:00']])
y = np.array(piv_tb['users'])
X.shape
```

(7303, 3)

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
asignar=[]
for row in y:
    asignar.append(row)
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2], c=asignar)
```

ValueError: c of shape (7303,) not acceptable as a color sequence for x with size 7303, y with size 7303

Any idea why I'm getting this error and how to solve it?

Comment: I have a similar error here. Linking this question with a similar one: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51658832/i-am-trying-to-plot-clusters-with-unique-color-but-getting-error